# Error Building Hive on OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, maven, hive

Building Hive with Maven:

mvn clean install -Phadoop-2,dist

Java version:

```
$ java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)
```

I tried setting the following Parameters:

```
$ env | grep JAVA
    JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2048m
    _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx2048m

r$ env | grep MAVEN
    MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2048m
```

I also tried editing pom.xml and set maven-surefire-plugin

```
<argLine>-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine>



The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:462)
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:755)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:385)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.EndPosParser.storeEnd(EndPosParser.java:55)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Parser.literal(Parser.java:561)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Parser.term3(Parser.java:949)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Parser.term2(Parser.java:683)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Parser.term1(Parser.java:654)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Parser.term(Parser.java:610)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Parser.termRest(Parser.java:624)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unset _JAVA_OPTIONS, and set MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m". And you could install oracle java 7/8.

Comment: Same results: David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:hive davidlaxer$ !e
env | grep JAVA_OPTIONS
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:hive davidlaxer$ env | grep MAVEN
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m 
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:hive davidlaxer$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: sudo mvn clean install -Phadoop-2,dist--show-version --debug
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T10:37:52-07:00)
Maven home: /Users/davidlaxer/Downloads/apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:hive davidlaxer$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  72 Nov 27 08:27 /usr/bin/java -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:hive davidlaxer$ env | grep JAVA
JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2048m
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:hive davidlaxer$ which java
/usr/bin/java