# Error Building Hive on Mac OS X 10.10.1

Tags: java, maven, hive

Problem if I build without 'sudo' I get a permission problem

If I build with 'sudo' maven defaults to Java 1.6 which runs out of memory.

Build Command:

```
mvn clean install -Phadoop-2,dist 

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) on project hive: Error finding remote resources manifests: /Users/davidlaxer/hive/target/maven-shared-archive-resources/META-INF/NOTICE (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) on project hive: Error finding remote resources manifests
```

If I run 
sudo mvn clean install -Phadoop-2,dist

JVM runs out of memory

```
The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:462)
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:755)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:385)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.EndPosParser.storeEnd(EndPosParser.java:55)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Parser.literal(Parser.java:561)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Parser.term3(Parser.java:949)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Parser.term2(Parser.java:683)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Parser.term1(Parser.java:654)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Parser.term(Parser.java:610)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Parser.termRest(Parser
```

Environment info:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Building Hive on OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162822/error-building-hive-on-os-x-10-10-1-yosemite-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-h)

Comment: Don't build with Java 6 under `sudo`?

Comment: Nope.  The Java compiler runs out of memory. Environment variables and settings in pom.xml didn't help: $ env | grep JAVA
    JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2048m
    _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx2048m

r$ env | grep MAVEN
    MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2048m